# System doesn't restart but sleeps when asked too (kde)

Tags: arch-linux, kde, reboot, intel, asus

When i press restart in kde it seems to shut down, but when i press a button it wakes up again, only to force itself into sleep again after a few seconds.

I use KDE Plasma 5.25.4
Linux arch 5.19.6-arch1-1

Comment: I think you should go to bios. Then look into restart button activity.

Comment: I Meant the restart in KDE

Comment: Then look for activity.